# How to Store/Create notification inside activity Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my Android FireBaseMsgReceiver Service, I am getting the notifications perfectly, what more I want is to Get those notification also inside an Activity, which now a days we can see on e-commerce apps, like Myntra, Can I use sharedprefrences, or any other method, I don't have any idea how to implement that.

```
 @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
         if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }    
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }      
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());     
    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    image = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);
    String title=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    message=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

            intent1 = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("TextData", message);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT );
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());


public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a persistent Database to save the notifications **Android-Room** or  **SqliteDatbase** etc. Do not use sharedprefrences .

Comment: you can either save notifications in database in your app or you can save notifications on server and fetch these notifications in your required activity by parsing the response

Comment: Can I use FireBase Realtime Database to store and retrieve those notifications? @MohitHooda

Comment: Can I use FireBase Realtime Database to store and retrieve those notifications? @ADM

Comment: Yeah why not . save the data to firebase in `onMessageReceived()`.

Comment: Yes you can save firebasedatabase and can save notifications in onMessageReceived()

Comment: Can you give me example of code for storing it on Firebase database & retrieving it on activity side?  @MohitHooda

Comment: Can you give me example of code for storing it on Firebase database & retrieving it on activity side?  @ADM

Comment: What example ? just follow the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).